# Enable URL Rewriting from config file - WebSphere Application Server (WAS 6.1)

Tags: session, url-rewriting, websphere

`URLRewriting` works fine if I have my server configured, like selecting the checkbox in administrative console of Server. But I want to enable it from configuration files like application deployment descriptor or other xml. We have session-config in `web.xml`, with which we can mention session timeout, similarly, Is there any way of configuring server to enable URL Rewriting without using admin console? Please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if you can change this setting via wsadmin? If thats possible you can automate that part in a script so that you don't require any manual interaction.

Comment: I can't run that script, if I do so the changes will be made on server, that will take effect for all the application.

Comment: @DownVoter, Please care to comment.

Comment: Its not me but regardless, did you not look at my answer ?

Comment: Yes I did! but no config files were created. I even looked inside other xmls.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment? Let me help you get this question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `META-INF/ibmconfig` in your EAR file.

Easiest way to do that is as following:

1. Deploy your EAR file.
2. Change the `Session Management` setting to whatever you want.
3. From the `Enterprise Applications` list select your application and click `Export`.

In the saved ear take a look at the `META-INF/ibmconfig`
Somewhere inside is `deployment.xml`, in there you will see the `sessionManagement` tag with your settings.

Adding the ibmconfig to your ear file META-INF (just copy it to your source folder) and packaging it will do what you want.

Comment: I could do the session management settings for server only, There is another session management configuration which is specific to application. I could see the configuration, but the checkbox for enabling the URL rewriting and other session management setting are disabled. May be it is because, the `Override session management` property is set to false. What I mean is I am unable to do as you said. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got a link about [Configuring session management by level](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftprs_cnfs.html). I don't see procedures told by them.

Comment: Are you deploying the ear with the admin console or with RAD (you can't set these settings if you deployed from RAD)

Comment: I am doing within RAD. How to do that outside? I am novice for this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: first remove the project from the server in RAD, then right click the ear project then export to ear, then in admin console application list click install select that ear and pretty much just click next next until finish. after that do what i told you in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything can be done with the [wsadmin scripts](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftxml_launchscript.html&resultof=%22wsadmin%22). Check the Info Center. There is a [getting started guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftxml_script.html)

After clicking in the GUI WAS can show you the script. However I'm not sure if that feature was alreay present in WAS 6.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mean we cannot configure in xml simply?

Comment: You could mess around in the various xml files. However It's error phrone and unsupported.

Comment: I don't have choice except configuring URLRewriting in application level